# Loading image for Marker saved in SQlite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, google-maps

I have saved the marker ID as well as the Image file path in my app using SQLite database.  The problem I am experiencing at the moment is when loading the map again the markers are displayed where the user has added them, but the image taken for that marker via camera intent (image path) does not load with the marker.

So to explain,  my markers have a `CustomInfoWindow` that the displays a title and snippet (location of marker) then has an `ImageView` which does display the image initially once the marker has been placed.  But when reloading the app the image is gone but the Title and Snippet is displayed.

So when saving the image file path and marker ID I use:

```
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE, markerId);
contentValues.put(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH, image.getAbsolutePath());
```

The data it saves is this:

```
m15  --> Marker ID
/storage/emulated/0/My Folder/MyImage_123.jpg --> File Path
```

And then when loading the markers once the app starts:

```
String filep = null;
String id = null;

id = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_IMAGE));
filep = arg1.getString(arg1.getColumnIndex(LocationsDB.FIELD_FILEPATH));

drawMarker(thePoint, title, snippet, id, filep);
```

So then in my `drawMarker` method:

```
private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String title, String snippet, String id, String filep) {
Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.title(title)
.snippet(snippet)
.position(thePoint)
.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
      .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
markerId = marker.getId();
```

And when dislaying the initial image, title and snippet:

```
@Override
  public View getInfoContents(Marker marker)
    {
View v  = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.infowindow_layout, null);
  ImageView markerIcon = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.marker_icon);
  TextView titleText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.TitleId);
  titleText.setText(marker.getTitle());
  TextView snippetText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.SnippetId);
  snippetText.setText(marker.getSnippet());
  Bitmap bitmap = myMarkersHash.get(marker.getId());
  markerIcon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
  return v;
```

So I know I need to somehow (in the drawMarker method) implement the `filep` and `id` so that i can display the image for that marker.  But am not sure how to do that.  I don't want to substitute the icon for the image instead i want the default marker with the image in the imageview.

I have been struggling with this for a couple of weeks now.  So now I am hoping that someone will be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:**

Sorry misunderstood you question.

You can save the file paths for specific markers via a HashMap, like this:

```
private HashMap<Marker, String> mMarkerImages = new HashMap<>();

private void drawMarker(LatLng point, String title, String snippet, String id, String filep) {
    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(title)
            .snippet(snippet)
            .position(thePoint)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE)));
    mMarkerImages.put(marker, filep);
}
```

Later you can use the same HashMap to fetch file path specific to some marker:

```
@Override
public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {
    String filep = mMarkerImages.get(marker);
    if (filep != null) {
        // File path was set for this marker, display your image
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,  But if i use that then the the default marker will be the image and not the standard plain old fashioned marker :-) Isn't there maybe a way of still keeping the marker and display the image in the imageView of the CustomInfoWindow?

Comment: Thanks,  but it seems that it still doesn't work.  I might be very tired at the moment so not concentrating all that much.  I'll work on it in the morning and get back to you.  Thanks again for your help.